# Group middleware not working in Laravel 8 for protected URL after logged in when hit login in URL it's show login page

Tags: laravel-8

After logged in I hit login in URL its show login page

```
 $path=$request->path();
        $emailcheck = session()->get('email');
        if(!Session::get('email') && $path !=="skc-admin/login"){
            //echo Session::get('email');
          return redirect('/');
            //echo $path;
         }elseif($path =="skc-admin/login" && Session::get('email') ){
            return redirect("skc-admin/dashboard");
         }
         return $next($request);
```

Comment: Did you put the "guest" middleware on your login route ?

Comment: No Sir --- Route::get("skc-admin/login", [AdminLoginController::class,'index'])->name('login');

Comment: Can you try to add middleware('guest') and see if you get the desired behaviour?